# MongoDB conditional aggregate

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I've got collection, inside in I have to calculate a price based on conditions if for selected dates (ie. from 2015/01/20 to 2015/01/22, 3 people) there is different pricing, if not then add a pricing.basic value plus if there are more persons than in personsIncluded I need to multiply.

Sample collection:

```js
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5473572cf1a76349020041c6"),
    "calendar" : [ 
        {
            "date" : ISODate("2015-01-20T12:41:20.000Z"),
            "status" : true
        }, 
        {
            "date" : ISODate("2015-01-21T12:41:20.000Z"),
            "status" : true,
            "pricing": {
                "basic": 9900,
                "perPerson": 1100
            }
        }, 
        {
            "date" : ISODate("2015-01-22T12:41:20.000Z"),
            "status" : true
        }, 
        {
            "date" : ISODate("2015-01-23T12:41:20.000Z"),
            "status" : false
        }, 
        {
            "date" : ISODate("2015-01-24T12:41:20.000Z"),
            "status" : false
        }, 
        {
            "date" : ISODate("2015-01-25T12:41:20.000Z"),
            "status" : false
        }
    ],
    "pricing" : {
        "basic" : 9470,
        "currency" : "USD",
        "personsIncluded" : 2,
        "perPerson" : 1000
    }
}
```

What I'm looking for:

```js
(
    if $calendar.date = currentSearchDate && $calendar.pricing
        $calendar.pricing + (($pricing.personsIncluded-personsInputValue) * ($calendar.perPerson ?: $pricing.perPerson))
    else
        ($pricing.basic + (($pricing.personsIncluded-personsInputValue) * $pricing.perPerson ))
) + (
    if $calendar.date = currentSearchDate2 && $calendar.pricing
        $calendar.pricing + (($pricing.personsIncluded-personsInputValue) * ($calendar.perPerson ?: $pricing.perPerson))
    else
        ($pricing.basic + (($pricing.personsIncluded-personsInputValue) * $pricing.perPerson ))
) + (
    if $calendar.date = currentSearchDate3 && $calendar.pricing
        $calendar.pricing + (($pricing.personsIncluded-personsInputValue) * ($calendar.perPerson ?: $pricing.perPerson))
    else
        ($pricing.basic + (($pricing.personsIncluded-personsInputValue) * $pricing.perPerson ))
) + ...
```

Of course only option is aggregation framework, but can it do something like this, or maybe it's gonna be better to get all results (filtered of course), push them into temporary collection and then sort & filter.

Comment: You should be able to do it in the aggregation framework using the `$cond`, `$add`, `$multiply`, etc. operators.

Comment: Hmmm, could you help me with this - even a little bit

Answer (score 0):

Have a look on that post :

[MongoDB conditional aggregation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30583484/mongodb-conditional-aggregation/30605731#30605731)

I have posted conditional aggregate, conditional filter is still missing.

This might help you.
If you still need help to build you aggregation let me know, i'll do my best to help you.

Comment: just replace true an false in my exemple by your price.