# MongoDB conditional aggregation

Tags: mongodb, conditional-statements

I would like to apply aggregation to conditions.

Suppose a I have 4 documents like this :

```
{
    "_id" : 1,
    "Action" : "Bufferize",
    "Active" : true,
    "Running" : true,
    "hasQuery" : true
}

{
    "_id" : 2,
    "Action" : "Numerize",
    "Active" : true,
    "Running" : false,
    "hasQuery" : false
}

{
    "_id" : 3,
    "Action" : "Resize",
    "Active" : false,
    "Running" : true,
    "hasQuery" : true
}

{
    "_id" : 4,
    "Action" : "Colorize",
    "Active" : true,
    "Running" : true,
    "hasQuery" : false
}
```

I would like the aggregation to send result :

1°) **if it exists at least one document having**

```
"Running" : true && "hasQuery" : true
```

**then filter on criteria (other documents)**  :

```
"hasQuery" : false && "Running" : false &&  "Active" : true
```

2°) **else ( with means if it exists document having)**

```
"Running" : true && "hasQuery" false 
|| "Running" : false && "hasQuery" true 
|| "Running" : false && "hasQuery" false
```

**then filter on criteria**

```
"Running" : false && "Active" : true
```

How to perform this aggregation ?

Comment: thanks JohnnyHK for corrections.

Comment: Problem was solved here.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30606996/mongodb-aggregation-sql-union-and-sql-exists-like-clause/30617662#30617662

Answer (score 0):

I have a first approch :

```
db.test_col.aggregate(
    {
         $project:
           {
             _id: 1,
               Running : 1,
               Active : 1,
               hasQuery : 1,
               Action : 1,
               RunningActiveRecordHasQuery:
               {
                 $cond: { if: { $and: [ "$Running", "$hasQuery",  "$Active"] }, then: true, else: false }
               },
               AnyNotRunningActiveRecordHavingNoQuery:
               {
                 $cond: { if: { $and: [ {$eq: [ "$Running", false ] }, {$eq : [ "$hasQuery", false]},  "$Active"] }, then: true, else: false }
               },
               AnyActiveRecordNotRunning:
               {
                 $cond: { if: { $and: [ {$eq: [ "$Running", false ] }, "$Active"] }, then: true, else: false }
               }             
           }
      }
)
```

it prints for exemple :

```
"Active" : true,
"Running" : true,
"hasQuery" : true,
"RunningActiveRecordHasQuery" : true,
"AnyNotRunningActiveRecordHavingNoQuery" : false,
"AnyActiveRecordNotRunning" : false
```

or :

```
"Active" : true,
"Running" : false,
"hasQuery" : true,
"RunningActiveRecordHasQuery" : false,
"AnyNotRunningActiveRecordHavingNoQuery" : false,
"AnyActiveRecordNotRunning" : true
```

Now Conditional filter is missing...
I'm still searching and will post answer when found !

Comment: Probleme was solved here :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30606996/mongodb-aggregation-sql-union-and-sql-exists-like-clause/30617662#30617662